# Why is UTC time in 2005 different than UTC time in 2006

Tags: c#, datetime

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(new DateTime(2006, fromDate.Month, fromDate.Day),TimeZoneInfo.Local)

{7/24/2006 **4:00:00 AM**}
Date: {7/24/2006 12:00:00 AM}
Day: 24
DayOfWeek: Monday
DayOfYear: 205
Hour: 4
Kind: Utc
Millisecond: 0
Minute: 0
Month: 7
Second: 0
Ticks: 632893104000000000
TimeOfDay: {04:00:00}
Year: 2006

TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(new DateTime(2005, fromDate.Month, fromDate.Day),TimeZoneInfo.Local)

{7/24/2005 **5:00:00 AM**}
Date: {7/24/2005 12:00:00 AM}
Day: 24
DayOfWeek: Sunday
DayOfYear: 205
Hour: 5
Kind: Utc
Millisecond: 0
Minute: 0
Month: 7
Second: 0
Ticks: 632577780000000000
TimeOfDay: {05:00:00}
Year: 2005
```

Comment: Maybe your country changed from/to using daylight savings between those years?

Comment: Maybe it was summer time in your local time in 2005? Tell us your local time :-)

Comment: Outputs correctly for me. What's your timezone info?

Comment: Could you try 2011 instead of 2006? Does it change anything?

Comment: DST did change from 2005 to 2006.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_Policy_Act_of_2005

Comment: @DanielCumings That's a change of a few days, and you are safely within the period that has not changed.

Comment: The issue was that I had my machine set to Eastern(Indiana) instead of Eastern.  In 2005 they did not observe DST and they adopted DST in 2006.

Comment: @DanielCumings I was about to post this :) I ran this program and saw the change:             foreach (var tz in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()) {
                Console.WriteLine("------- {0} ----------", tz);
                var a = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(new DateTime(2005, 7, 24), tz);
                Console.WriteLine(a);
                var b = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(new DateTime(2006, 7, 24), tz);
                Console.WriteLine(b);
            }

Comment: That would have given me the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I had my machine set to Eastern(Indiana) instead of Eastern. In 2005 they did not observe DST in Indiana(http://www.timeanddate.com/time/us/indiana-time.html) and they adopted DST in 2006.  Switching my machine back to Eastern Time Zone fixed the issue.